# Setting state causes a UI lag in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have a react app that renders a list of cards in a container widget. The container widget has a useEffect where we subscribe to an observable and update the array that is then used to render the cards inside the component. Each time any of the cards change, the observable emits new values resulting in creating of the array all over again and thus all the cards are re-rendered. However this re-render causes a noticeable UI lag.

Here is the stripped down version of code from the container component.

```
const obsRef = useRef<Subscription>(null);
const [apiResArray, setApiResArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    
    if(obsRef.current) obsRef.current.unsubscribe();

    const mySubscription = myObservable$(changingValue)
    .subscribe((val) => {
        setApiResArray(val.apiArray);
    });

    obsRef.current = mySubscription;

    return () => {
      obsRef.current && obsRef.current.unsubscribe();
    };

}, [changingValue])
```

```
return (
    <CardWrapper $showMenu={showMenu}>
        { apiResArray.map((res, resIndex) => {
            return (
                <Card
                    data={{
                        // a json object with props
                    }}
                    key={res?.hKey}
                />
            );
        })}
    </CardWrapper>
);
```

The `Card` component here simply renders the content based on props passed to it. I know that since data is an Object, referential equality may fail and I have tried memoizing the component but even that does not help.

There is a lot more to these components but posting all the code won't make sense. I wish to understand what possibly might be causing the list re-render to be such a heavy operation that the whole UI gets stuck for a second or two. The array contains around only 100 objects or so. It happens whenever `changingValue` changes. I can share more information as required.

Any suggestions on improving the performance are highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear why you are re-subscribing every time `changingValue` is updated. Do you need `changingValue` to be a dependency for the `useEffect`, if it's not being referenced in the `useEffect` itself?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Updated the code. The observable needs `changingValue`.

Comment: Is a card's key changing when the array is updated?

Comment: So the array is updated either when the user interacts with one of the cards or when the `changingValue` changes. So when a user interacts with the Card, it is removed from the array. All the other cards still carry the same keys in this case. However, if the `changingValue` changes, it generates a whole new set of Cards where all keys are different.

Comment: Updating a Card's props and/or its key is going to cause it to rerender.

Answer (score 0):

React will **mount and unmount** the component in **DEV** mode to validate effect cleaner and any side effect.

I'm concerned about that subscribe and unsubscribe in your effect.

If you want changingValue to be defined why not just wrap it inside an if statement ?

```js
if (changingValue) {
    const mySubscription = myObservable$(changingValue)
    .subscribe((val) => {
        setApiResArray(val.apiArray);
    });

    obsRef.current = mySubscription;
}
```

Another observation is at render of items

```js
<Card
  data={
    {
      // a json object with props
    }
  }
  key={res?.hKey} // Why is this a falsy value ?
/>
```

Falsy value can make key prop change those re-rendering the component, one with React internal key value and another with your implementation value

Comment: The changingValue will change as the user interacts with the app. Therefore, I need to ensure that apiResArray has the corresponding list of items only related to the current changingValue' value. Hence the subscription. It will always be a valid value. The key, similarly, will also always be a valid value.